# Using multiple conditions in a do...while loop

Tags: c++

So I'm making a program that asks a user if they want to do something. The answer is as simple as Y/N. I would like the program to be able to accept both capital and lowercase "Y". Problem is, when I type `while (answer == 'Y', answer == 'y')` only the lowercase "Y" is accepted. If I type `while (answer == 'y', answer == 'Y')`

What am I doing wrong?

(More info: "answer" is the name of my "char" variable, and I'm using the "iostream", "cstdlib", and "string" libraries)

Comment: Just curious, why would you even think that a comma might work this way? Is there another language, in which it does?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw something in Java done like that. It was a while ago and I don't have the best memory, so it's anyone's guess really.

Comment: @DonReba maybe because you can do something like `for ( i=0, j=0; i+j<8; i++, j++)` in c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the 'logical or' operator `||`

So your code would become `while (answer =='Y' || answer == 'y')`

Comment: Thank you sir. I honestly had no idea there even was a logical 'or' operator in existence. Needless to say, things work now. Giving you the answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the logical operator for `or` ("||"):

```
while( answer=='Y' || answer=='y' ){  
       //code
}
```

Also, FFR:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) instead of an "or" operator, like the logical or, `||`.

From Wikipedia:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a **binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type)**. The comma operator has
>   the lowest precedence of any C operator, and acts as a sequence point.
>   (emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

Its the comma operator's property to return the second operand only (it executes both operands though). Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    int i=1, j=2, k=3;
    int l= (i,cout<<"print; ",j,k);
    cout << l;
}
```

Because of the comma operator, output is 'print; 3'.
So try avoiding this comma operator in your code, and as stated above by many, use instead a logical (`||`) operator.